# Update multiple rows from subquery

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update multiple rows from subquery. Note that ID is the primary key in the table.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT tm.ID, tm.LocID  = (SELECT CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 1 THEN MAX(LocID) END
                 FROM   tblLoc tl
                 WHERE  tl.LocID = tm.LodID )
FROM   tblMain tm
```

Here is my update statement:

```
Update tblMain
set LocID = TMP.LocID
(
  SELECT tm.ID, tm.LocID  = (SELECT CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 1 THEN MAX(LocID) END
                 FROM   tblLoc tl
                 WHERE  tl.LocID = tm.LodID )
  FROM   tblMain tm

) AS TMP
where tblMain.ID = TMP.ID
```

I get incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Update tblMain
set LocID = TMP.LocID
FROM tblMain INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT tm.ID, tm.LocID  = (SELECT CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 1 THEN MAX(LocID) END
                 FROM   tblLoc tl
                 WHERE  tl.LocID = tm.LodID )
  FROM   tblMain tm

) AS TMP
ON tblMain.ID = TMP.ID
```

Comment: could you alias tblMain with, say, m, so it's update m set... from m inner join... on m.id = tmp.id

Comment: yes you could do that too but the error was in syntax so I just fixed that.